# Wrap selected text with bbcode tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, rich-text-editor, bbcode

I'm attempting to make an *extremely* simple rich-text editor that wraps the selected text in bbcode tags.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function wrapText(elementID, openTag, closeTag) {
    var textArea = document.getElementById(elementID);

    if (typeof(textArea.selectionStart) != 'undefined') {
        var begin = textArea.value.substr(0, textArea.selectionStart);
        var selection = textArea.value.substr(textArea.selectionStart, textArea.selectionEnd - textArea.selectionStart);
        var end = textArea.value.substr(textArea.selectionEnd);
        textArea.value = begin + openTag + selection + closeTag + end;
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<button type="button" onclick="wrapText('edit','[b]','[/b]');" >B</button>
<button type="button" onclick="wrapText('edit','[i]','[/i]');" >I</button>
<button type="button" onclick="wrapText('edit','[u]','[/u]');" >U</button><br />
<textarea id="edit" name="message" rows="10" cols="50">
This is some example text.
</textarea><br />
<br /><input type="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This seems to work fine for the most part, except in IE it only works in version 10.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mJmur/1/)

What can I add or change in order to make this more cross-browser compatible so it will work with IE 8?

I'm not opposed to using jQuery, but I'd really prefer not to unless it is really [this complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245968/textarea-toggle-selection-tags-with-javascript) without it.

Comment: Open your console, `wraptext` is not defined ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mJmur/1/